# Installing Notepad++ via WINE on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, notepad++, wine

After moving to Linux, I miss having Notepad++ with me and I want to bring it along to my new environment.

I have Wine installed and downloaded the `npp.5.8.5.Installer.exe`. I have no idea what directory or where this `.exe` exists or if I have to query Wine or what.

How do I install Notepad++ via Wine on Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: `apt-get install geany`

Comment: The advices you've found when googling make sense. Linux users don't give such advices because they are elitist or mean or whatever. Some notorious text editors, notably vim and emacs, have both Linux and Windows versions. Notepad++ doesn't, even if it's based on scintilla, which is not tied to a single OS. You have a problem with notepad++ and if it doesn't run well via wine, your option is to pester its devs to port it to Linux.

Comment: use geany, it is comparable to np++.

Answer (score 8):

1. Install Wine:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wine
   ```
2. Configure version (Windows 8 works for me) and drives (Autodetect, `../drive_c` points to `~/.wine/drive_c/`):

   ```
   winecfg
   ```
3. Install:

   ```
   wine ~/Downloads/npp.7.3.3.Installer.exe
   ```

   Running directly after install may cause the plugins list not to load. It also appears that Plugin Manager 1.3.5 is the latest supported by Wine, as attempting to update the Plugin Manager broke the plugins list.
4. Run:

   ```
   wine "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
   ```

   Or via menu if you don't like debug output. Note that 32-bit programs on 64-bit Windows are in `Program Files (x86)` and that [64-bit Notepad++ doesn't come with the Plugin Manager](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2459).
5. Uninstall:

   ```
   wine uninstall
   ```

   Run again to make sure it's gone.

Comment: ```sudo apt-get install wine-stable``` on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I've since switched to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Notepad++ (*notepad-plus-plus*) is a snap package in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install Notepad++ open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus
```

To add Notepad++ navigation to other drives besides the default drive:

```
sudo snap connect notepad-plus-plus:removable-media
```

[image]

Comment: Works OK on my Xubuntu 16.04 box, but the little code completion popup window seems to steal the focus temporarily from the main window every time a key is pressed which causes missing keystrokes when typing quickly. Initially the font wasn't monospace (as it is under Windows), to change that I went to *Settings -> Style Configurator* menu, chose *Default Style* under the *Global Styles* language and changed the font to *FreeMono*.

Comment: To remove the code completion popup window, go to Settings->Preferences...->Auto-Completion and untick Enable auto-completion on each input.

Answer (score 3):

Just run the installer with wine.

```
$ wine npp.5.8.5.Installer.exe
```

That should just work as long is it is an app that "plays nice".

You should also see an icon in your gnome or KDE menu.

But.... yes, Vim is better. ;-)

Comment: wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\npp.5.8.5.Installer.exe"

Comment: IIRC, you have to configure wine first, I think it's winecfg or something. I can't verify now since I don't have wine installed. I'm sure there are docs... You might have one or two issues. See http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=13036

Answer (score 3):

This worked perfectly for me and it later survived an upgrade from Ubuntu 16.4.3 to 18.4.1 no problem.  (I since discovered Sublime-text which is pretty good because it highlights reserved words, strings, table names and aliases differently, and it supports a simple code-formatter extension.)
Fri Jun 15 12:35:45 SAST 2018

1. Enable 32bit on a 64bit environment ([more...](https://www.unixmen.com/enable-32-bit-support-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10-greater/))

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
2. Install the latest version of Wine ([more...](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu))

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
   wine --version
   ```

   *:~$ wine-3.0.1*
3. Configure version (Windows 8 worked for me) and drives (Autodetect, `../drive_c` points to `~/.wine/drive_c/`)

   ```
   winecfg
   ```
4. Add mono .NET interpreter.  ([more...](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/))

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
   sudo apt install apt-transport-https
   echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
   sudo apt update
   ```
5. Open *win32* applications with `wine` from *Program Files (x86)*

   ```
   wine "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
   ```
6. FYI: You can explore the wine environment with a dos shell

   ```
   wine cmd
   ```

Comment: @bertieb, how's that...?

Comment: Huge improvement! Excellent edit :)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly in my experience Notepad++ does not work well in Ubuntu with Wine.  The closest Linux text editor I could find that was somewhat similar to Notepad++ was [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html).

Comment: I assume that's because both notepad++ and scite use scintilla.

Comment: @vtest I had never thought about it, but now that you mention it, yes, I'm sure that is why.

Comment: It works very well? What OS are you using? -- I am using Linux Mint, XFCE Desktop, wine config is pointing to WIN XP.

Comment: I've also had great success with notepad++ via Wine in Linux Mint.

Comment: @davidparks21 please note that I answered this question 7 years ago. There have been a lot of updates to Wine and NP++ in that time.

Comment: I don't mean any disrespect to your answer, I only mean to make it most relevant now, it is currently being found via google searches. Things change over time, that's normal. The other answer is better suited to current needs and thus voting should reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the zip distribution of Notepad++ 6.4.2 and launched `notepad++.exe` with `wine`.

So far it works.

Answer (score 0):

Update you wine installation to latest version.

First enable 32-bit architecture -

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then add `winehq` repository key -

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ <your version of Ubuntu> main'
```

Update -

```
sudo apt update
```

Install wine -

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

you can check your wine version using -

```
wine --version
```

At the time of writing it is  - `wine-6.0`

Go to  - [Notepad Plus Plus download site](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/)

At the time of writing the latest release is `Notepad++ 8.1.9.1`

Download 32-bit or 64-bit installer with `.exe` extension

At the time of writing latest 32-bit installer is - `npp.8.1.9.1.Installer.exe` and 64-bit installer is `npp.8.1.9.1.Installer.x64.exe`

Use `wine` to install it -

For 32-bit -

```
wine npp.8.1.9.1.Installer.exe
```

For 64-bit -

```
wine64 npp.8.1.9.1.Installer.x64.exe
```

The windows installer dialog menu appears. Follow the instructions to finish the installation.

Once installation is complete open Ubuntu Applications Menu or search for Applications and you will get - `Notepad++`